# Creating test harness for Cordova app, whats the deal?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, testing, appium

I have the task of creating a Test Harness for a Cordova built mobile application.
Thus far, all of my test scripts are automation scripts....
Is it viable to test the entire application using solely automation tests?
I cannot find any documentation regarding normal logical testing of the source code? Am i missing something can some one point in the right direction I'm quite lost.

Comment: The "logical testing of the source code" is commonly called unit testing. Appium cannot test source code of the app, as it only has information about the UI elements of the app and as such is always black box testing.

For unit testing take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/index.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/01-introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH1-SW1 for platform specific unit testing information

Comment: ok thank you, unfortunately Cordova logic is written in javaScript not Java